# propertyProviderClass custom implementation with Jasypt not working

Tags: java, oracle, liquibase

I have a custom Properties class extending java.util.Properties and overriding getProperty using Jasypt.

I have placed Jasypt and MyProperties jar files under the lib folder of Liquibase.

I am trying to run it with Liquibase-CLI:

`liquibase --defaultsFile=my.properties --propertyProviderClass=info.farhdine.MyProperties validate`

But, I am always getting an error:

`java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`

In my.properties file, even if nothing is encrypted, I am always getting the same error as far as I use propertyProviderClass.

Does anyone already managed to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!
I was overriding the get() method instead of put() :)

```
public class MyProperties extends java.util.Properties {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -207802321379271320L;

public MyProperties() {
    StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
    encryptor.setPassword("jasypt");
    super.defaults = new EncryptableProperties(encryptor);
}

@Override
public synchronized Object put(Object paramK, Object paramV) {
    return super.defaults.put(paramK, paramV);
}
}
```