# java liquibase maven plugin safe store password

Tags: java, maven, liquibase

Im using liquibase in a standard java project (non spring) and using maven to manage my migrations and rollbacks

to the plugin configuration in maven im passing a liquibase.properties file that currently has a plain password in it

here is the relevant code

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

and the properties file

```
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
username=test
password=test
changeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/changelog-master.xml
```

how can i avoid this

Comment: You can specify the configuration properties in the plugin configuration section, and reference environment variables using ${env.VAR_NAME}

Answer (score 0):

You may use your own property provider class to handle encryption. I don't see any docs for this but you can browse the commits on [this link](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1932), it might help.

Also the answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325560/propertyproviderclass-custom-implementation-with-jasypt-not-working) will help you with using `propertyProviderClass` in liquibase.

Other than this, you can go through [this article](https://apexplained.wordpress.com/2015/08/08/password-encryption-in-the-liquibase-maven-plugin/) to have an idea.